# Bundle install doesn't install gem from private git repo

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile

Something strange is happening, everything used to work fine a few hours ago.

I have a private gem as dependency to a project. I've added the private gem git repo as follows:

```
gem 'my-awesome-gem', '>=1.2.3', git: 'https://john:pass123@bitbucket.org/johndoe/my-awesome-gem'
```

When doing `bundle install` it shows:

```
...
Using my-awesome-gem 1.2.3 from https://john:pass123@bitbucket.org/johndoe/my-awesome-gem (at master@bc19e27)
Bundle complete! 5 Gemfile dependencies, 21 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But this gem doesn't show when I do `gem list`. Also, when I do `pry -r my-awesome-gem` or require it in the project it returns:

```
! Unable to load application: LoadError: cannot load such file -- my-awesome-gem
/Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- my-awesome-gem (LoadError)
...
```

I've been playing around for a few hours but can't find the problem. I've tried reinstalling ruby via rbenv. I'm using Ruby 2.4.1 via rbenv.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Bundler you must engage Bundler in any code you use. That means either:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'my-awesome-gem'
```

Or:

```
pry -r bundler/setup -r my-awesome-gem
```

The gem is installed, it's just not in your `$LOAD_PATH` until you get Bundler to load in the `Gemfile` and find all the dependencies.